# Finalized block got stuck

Tags: substrate-node

StaFi chain has been running stably for a long time using version v2.0.0 of substrate, and the current version is v0.6.2. But the finalized block suddenly got stuck. Can check details here:
https://telemetry.polkadot.io/#list/0x290a4149f09ea0e402c74c1c7e96ae4239588577fe78932f94f5404c68243d80.

More information:

Code: https://github.com/stafiprotocol/stafi-node/tree/v0.6.2

Subscan: https://stafi.subscan.io/

Apps: https://apps.stafi.io/

We didn't find any error or useful logs for this. And we also tried to use the grandpa.noteStalled function to try to restore((https://stafi.subscan.io/extrinsic/0xe4431deafd133d9cdfcd952a610b58cad0a53ce026d33c83e7c90b91a6efbb2a).), actually we even tried multiple times using higher height, but all didn't work.

About the GRANDPA round state,

```
curl https://stafi-rpc.stafi.io \
 -X POST \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data '{"method":"grandpa_roundState","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'
```

The result is:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"background":[],"best":{"precommits":{"currentWeight":0,"missing":["5C6aCJLKMX26VrgWUyCGBWu8mv6nxuXwMm6Fc9znDXBiyS4r","5C6iPsqiYwdFaKHydnYjVz7e95oY3tWCCD999H5e4NopCEiq","5C77whr2H4GEqrv7QFXCXnSa3FAWEUGSTTdYKCbaNN5KRKXC","5CEgrkayB6z7V547jv3VdzP4Kts7299xB3Yu3koJ4ztCPKb8","5CGptCyfLjvC42My8cPKfRadSyGcZNMtQUsS4KmmLiMevAYJ","5CH9PxoqR1CdL5gXnhEqiHhx5ykre4ZaEY58NtCKPjCRYecR","5CHDkm33a6wawMagg7M4CGpeYXtYWgbsWRPzrs4iFGTU4S6j","5CKjcnHcCspYD974BDJ8JWXcL3Xt1DxuPbhQkE1RvcnuUTBK","5CLJTem1DvDwmbRiWwX43KXHyYY5SWZ2f2KpJwFiX2zy9u9W","5CMDtbm4XM9W617XnRUC5YvDHTpUYHHqXuSwU6omfGEgfxAY","5CMf5pWBYBnaag7qVHhfXAeJKsx28Dufo6Z1ekMd8fDqCzpY","5CQbFzpuv45gFRE4QKtEmPGskk7FCeU6trdSyTJFukYUZQcA","5CU7UvWgaqbhbH2FxgPh8bn4YXjmkpsiSKLzXh425fKeCeMQ","5CYFfX66GcHfdTRMw1XgS226GJvdvaq8SmsnqFQerRPKJZr5","5CYUkvh2jmQkgm4AT6YvwLDaE7CJK3zmkg7ZtUvavmGsFSQF","5CaBuc5t3hUHWfeR5hzLSn7DKhyZkEDZPZamkTwAyGewkMVp","5CbTsqZ4mivxxC6mP4Lok99FcLxTi2aKNAMUFEEiR8d966CU","5Cbbzng1xa9gaKuGv5uvRyHDcEUfJyyGpPhfYf6szAykUzGP","5CdHYrqsTYmWDoQTE378Y43deqgBccTPRR6Da7tttESSP3GP","5CeCBEcBEVAijVq8UfDwb1pE7ecu5hBZbw2EL6BgGxgco4pb","5CfLQDTeEF6T3XaMnUbqtDavp6CZ52Hmk5Hz2Fk6mpoHrH5g","5CfaUE5tfk8U9wJeD7MEKBsQHyuF9QVSetNiBzDhZYpPcPh5","5CgWrhMkTMnoocdN14832aS1MSbkzX5x8BWeHheeESjUNkXQ","5CgypggyXgs6DAF7GS3qrNFE23QG1WkqJNf8VWKgNvVDxHep","5CigHitVJtDu3GAPw3d6xGGf3kTnhDwHQcmYMcbXWxzb1qau","5CkUvBBYtLKCxetHZ9V8MTnKSjoHGuBQaaTzCSz7Y5eWGwWD","5CoRZZLMnwD2GXUHkAyFeQrHVkUHDPWQCmySpnsf2b86Ybpp","5CrTcCRMBQ5RPwGJ7ew5C89PB9MpPg6q1jHUGMDqDRS71ZFs","5Cu7KaNzkhKMjuz3KdGuRXyCxUSbt3oLRFWFKvXZLQPTSQph","5CwezFdooNCR5jcFi1q6ruLXBYynZczw1KLnkYvjoncYwe4X","5D3MSZ89shhZtr8SFbqf6w54cRSQPRvQY4SbEMq2H25yA6tg","5D43eVvZeQgKWKPUDEBt2PYYDVWtdFPrNT9cuomQvNrAkpcr","5D5hiWsdwL1227pK7PNvkHpnw3hRQLKXQEqy1sXvL3HFyDEy","5D5mFWCfZjcZ6qq558in79fz1r6v6K54TwhUn8FTukzrymuQ","5D6GqWTm2Ry97aU6AtHXZLwbZNVCB49kK4kpLfxAGmn5QCDz","5D77y3kk2F4WeVGPFGNKHj9KqFDkL3Be78sBN1jLwQ2MNRJm","5DCAzhXx1xH6dcbcLCmpNv9HU4kwriEzSKJmLunGJDT4rcZj","5DFyPTcYq2UeQyfD7wW1qxWghjDbfkg1jCZDDNXpqz9Dqmdn","5DHG85ALQLBZEv5VcJS4PHf3JuURoVYSZ8Vky43s2ez9kNnc","5DKV3RdcGuC8YszRNhdF1h6NsfpYSUpxLjMUTGuLKFoWXntq","5DLDwu8BA1nF3243Htp8BprXrbwY47WFBP5uDMWKKjTMdBjb","5DM9HDFujkCJyHCno68C8qeLX43KbafRdLBzyi1hwzrYdfn1","5DNrhBQiYfCK4gKSPKQhym5W3JWnuWDYkLVhCNWW2PdeTZYJ","5DQDJamT5h7vTjKbhQvEzhHnp1Qm6r3ThxbtdTrK82sT5kQ4","5DU4ykjP5YtuPrCsMmZd7FRkMSVJzv8GoQ6oRsREhUPtf2wx","5DUeSNipPoh4JV7uVpN6AjxYNa8jPyMYA5KutQuPe5F26Bsm","5DYYLvzZ7KyNGmaiSCsxTgnhoAdYD916bBktJQ6bLRYpon29","5DZ16AhB2C56oNGhK4SsVUbMQ4w4fXGFR9i94BjryS6gGewH","5DZXPZG7jENTGEietsJv3GNoZjhJkUXVW7wcVkfADfxhuEdE","5DcJ48Tw5WsYULGjU6AGFWRq7T7f2ShNPEbp2Snp9VAd3Wj5","5DeBfxVzRXZPchtU1JwuKFwb4ybzh7PaABTWDPuoNhynmUVi","5DfwGhCQUDTEyZQBXJMm9gVF6K8KZNYRcTLJtCNoLaTn3X7o","5DgwgFj1NXC9dm3HZArna6rW9T3aAKZC5ZfvZM5kwtBirDN9","5DhHepwhWomV6ysktT12KJ818F3X6StwmBNwMYdPZecf2cmx","5DjqAz7EyjHttZDP972zP4RT3Fmn4hsexg5LoD7qhpsdGi65","5DqLoPQNxSBqhKxStFmsX9LHyq6TqS1Qbhg9mKBk1ZZM4iX7","5DrVCAcuRrbt6JFXGijxXupvBbcH9YQPcS7FCk6zZRtPxDts","5DsMNJNQas581gjpkSx5ZZiDSavKwhnksogwrU1Haz26DQ5f","5DxRcRUuGqrGxG1uMG45FKVSVsc39UWUfSqzWiK79wvF8Sb1","5DxxJYA3J6nUjShY4ZWZYsm4b7KbKFLiPpqLmNT5rmq1ozSK","5E5ZUXUwvS5zsV86vgYRfsdD77qta3uKnTvYMohg6ZkakC1u","5E8RRWQp1EUbhoWYwbKc36dCAvWchCtsMTPxkQffj7awBQkz","5E9Sru6GEbiDjq4CiZuf2r77JViHEdVbjbdGaBhwGfXfFw9e","5ECjdwFTgwZ59973WFa2Epui6vmm6mj867H2oX6nG6MPC5gL","5EEdXcAxmDWLEZxzQZSZYBGxNoj1RAy8hAVw9FRqqBpSpmaZ","5EHWX4FAVTEzzCxFqcvhj4sdtcqkMdVhgNggk1Sf9ZXnUQYA","5ELTnqE1MMxnYCq54hLwQ4vUSXWLyUqDpHxBLpkkCfs7WyeD","5ENNUCoTrovy5QC7kMA3Tc7mRMVaBVpBYuwtxiHZ71v2jGZa","5ESnrMXJnp4Hjkv7gmbvUmXYbA1Udfher13fAiNWgaTKwtp9","5EWNkZYTrA65pfjwbSScMUk7cWM6WKTbUsdrr2Rz4sBF8XWL","5EZ4ERq36gwnLLJzNvtYVmLLU7XEcGUBJcfDe5jypVPd1i1i","5EbLYciVfxXHoh5QZadWPH9nmAEA6hAnW2dArKMTx4fjYoZH","5Eci1K8B1m6eEWaiqsr4xvb6cg6tajW9GTcnz6GrpYqUYfBK","5EkdkAeBynRZNn7AiE3f6zKnZjco5tuyVN1NFAxmLoePX5DP","5EkguJE7pbwi88YHjDh8GkDbgtFJf65qnGyzHJTSFfxT3JPt","5Eo8nBRNuLaerm5TrFDWrbBGLGu65WY8iKsjdYLTrTHkz2zr","5EoXzBrWfTRAePhGeznVKjvY4rWAzyfk33871Bb3cWQgHVc5","5EroE5BJV7n93Z4D9dmpaARa817iHQJ1UyauoYmJFZppKDUB","5Erq9uUZt5jyhBVDZ4d3pHYperB6KXo8pH2rDnnQPN4VwPSu","5EtZ1a2Fq51MzTgU8fJuY3yADytSfRq2N9svjVv1xTMpnkY1","5EvtGF6W1Xws4ouGdPofgJNFCT6nHR3o3h9oUCkjyUEBsDTk","5F3uDi2ghwFEXEoPMNGiwZmPz6C7DpYdYBejSPjeTwnvrUAK","5F4HbX6C7NRkmuiDZULMoehGTkywNKwMsx9qbCv36QnTEUSb","5F914LRb584dKbz3rakrcB3Uhnk9DyZYfxPL8J8meUX3sLeH","5FA8sjGw8keLJnc1e1fCPgs653QaX7iTPfUPst9PFnSeGxbt","5FBrPeS4tdK4GyaqVXDN2FKMP5KzYPdf9z844gAkDJtPvevH","5FGQCahYL2jBTPsAw7x9trSWGkDETTNiz51sr25QMW2hgh7A","5FJr162Efkw1VQXZHzKpNptrpCnr4fhAyn724pvpyAmGKXb6","5FMfXdTNyDRuL2C8dhTWBbZfYXf3TBjNXpA2tvadggGRtAhh","5FPmy3YjGdWZm3roYNUrFVAeZa1GjbubWs4SccxW4xk1BHV6","5FPsTKk3uhfrSEtJ3YHo7NnTRoktcUybd1AceKhMniLvjSGn","5FQ93DD4nAfR6LmPK4oHE8Sg5MhHSjt31kJTzhg7L3hzfmEd","5FSCwHAdwuJyn1bJ6QA7QaF2YERdMHZLCkkC5p7iXqHpkapp","5Fa6DVLQfvHe5K5ZKZNsCBnNF7aQaWLP7YNLLc6VJBocZBWC","5FbqdfDvdEMU1c24hsyBGjdNt4FT9A6QkiSVpfz5mGm4qHVj","5FcY1F9o9kx5ZwcvYdHuRQ1cgVHA47A435N5SgpeThLgYfkY","5FcjA9UriUwjKxiNHKN4ksPFqaATRPW9vAUxytfK1V34ektM","5FdeKnHxCFDmhAMHwWZKUv4hMseXTxNVDS613YMdRsZcV9ca","5FeaGCh2iwy7pU2nUHFQ8yLGYdujURCU9kyadhW8x95TekA3","5FgCjHUF45dEqw5wAAyuciCUFEs4y53WHQysfSK1Kq2EEFrx","5FiqJD5egss5dKquDJXbGobyzThiQqQcPTSAJwavy1R26c5P","5FjbApWu1dMdYTdRCxoS8ni3woS2UbhftgYXWWR2edtqQ1Dt","5Fm4DozqYZaUkYUekj9sDCYpuG3TXtVqci4jrU79yC3acTyq","5FmBzzPq1cLKirE7tCv3JoM3UVy3a62rJFish8tFLnipVJa9","5FmLtqymKPK2dDBYfq2qe7iomCZLq9eyyaSGmBmsYaZv9pv1","5FoiAwAFd6EybrzRMZffGPqLr1ccWsZA92ZNKvp4q5ZQcCeW","5FoidQ5KHELQCfj7YsHRBLXW7YMDRiirkLYhTybGQmHhYrev","5FqQxvjui7uuAcVq7RcJFVBL1sphH44YTRN7Mdn8aqBCv6dD","5Fr5PH4198YgsudLPgfGvmGcYVYx6DwPfNXDncPMCWqW4kAi","5FtVb6D6zuLQMEt2S83VsjNra1BFRoYgrGsm6yqRHDBeK447","5Fu5J9E1TuNcwu8LDk5sdZihx9subju329ChDMXyKAPCPjL4","5FxepAXJtyxNxkJvVvwnpssQHiBQcunRoN7BSqmFa2hQ8Qbv","5FzyvzWqL73NM1QviAyrCAHKx4V8mEzbTSr7CnvyzhUyAy8e","5G4DN9gaKh48LraEQNNhKKGBiWHq3hXr9haPaHpRLEcsQXpk","5G8yJv4XemYeNFc253HCy4kZbDR8DPSoqrMM9kP9GWnn226s","5GBVSftmUYbpHQdxDMxH4aVJs1s4Z3g3bHTYhP9X4kMnyg21","5GC9BJfGXihQ2nUSarfFZ4zdM6KiTeZZLLScUVHHr4voAPVm","5GCJTafeJRyAMp7cAEjQwVTFNmBVh9vUX8Jq8MAyXCwwkJLm","5GDKAHHBprcmVgPqDJQzy2sPaShVS96No5JqTwiPcRDWnNUz","5GGE5mdUM2dncReKfLLbLizqYPSokNz4Tj4Z2n8Kr7DLPrqE","5GGscd7C9EJdb9KJ2Cv9VfwQsERSPiNCdzybWsvJ8WnLB9jW","5GJTkvpQgU8RJwBAiAFnYP4inov6n6Zir2QTPNuwn1C1V4MH","5GMvuYcVXDZ7s17aCu2eLSc9vS2YaGoLoHB5Di4DTAPYnpx2","5GNpMeddxEyxj5bqqJHemEuz11LiAzb6PvAiY976X4WvNMfW","5GP7prKCRVuSVkq48VRU98dMP9urPFqF4zq5TAG6rbQUNwv7","5GSE35fHbBY8zdWNjG32auZ7sEBmCwyg3ejaCRSC6WdgdZxB","5GVsAxku9Ps7XoXFaVgEKdRHtgPzKVeuVsWUuDJ4z8ko3Bwt","5GYAJ8wjQiLsiofoHWdGFjJMnPvuayKLXUfxA745XakPKQNA","5GaMMwVnvDD3GnPLw1TVxzQG79m5U6EJGfiQYJd7CEG9ATXh","5GbtyseKmhUmQGa9k3z2UVpPx15A3yE2cAr6T7SKLDyBgS5Y","5Gk5JCbDs3JJtJEoNPQPj2rXBCE73UaYso2EfHZJ8uZKxcbz","5GkvH2KtWZGmkjzcTyHUr5GQcwhUJBKdXb8CCYV4i6am36xq","5GqcxpuwsoGqfMdkcmrS6Q13qDUcwkajeFGYTpQ5eUk3gjkp","5GrBDB6zjmQUSQgyGALr7CVUC44MFaArzo7TxxiqWbo8iL2E","5GunHjFHvFtBtKyiJszJkRBjQJ1JcZDupChbyGj5i5WxrwLU","5GwmAdQjEEr4iK7QT5FwTo9FrQvYSRiXmdCshkwYTCkGAin3","5H6PBYLnyj2XCLyJSxxtQ8GeSs6GHixw3qApLHovdV2gsNcc","5H72kw7M8KBQtmrpLh1Sx5rFSzKbn6ZbCMmfnKFjYBD7Umsd","5H8wCzaF4zSb2i1yj9Vdsbm4S612JBpq83ZWZXnwUukzxogQ","5H9WEykwSHmnCWUgCUwnqa9EorVt317DXHH49LCFkg8pvYEk","5HBoJbp4hTrGHhuxxwyYHaYMzeVnocbUcmE9joL2UNb4jLKU","5HBvshYQ1bHBEjTSNk7LhyM9Nb4wEiqMYVjH1pAutBrJecon","5HDgkH427uXtA8q1RcU6dNDsYdPFjYMhMEhrMb2R15dbLW8f","5HErtXo2LRVovBgMD6YF5CPUKgK6ZXRBKx8vj1kw2advTraH","5HGm8NwjzYmnHPSea5duXTzycvhWYwqjANGk4pmNZhv9EQ4h","5HGrncYcXzwr9FJet1S2xn4WgbSrKj3WZV3rfnyBqKsufC2f","5HLwyatqk2SGGUX4NVVq5zuT6woCFdrm4DsiAL98YJLSbsbv","5HSdfeX1uYLi6NrmTifJwZajS2zE2ZTd7jakHLPgzaqaZF2V","5HSjaKhotDaemQXuQhrfPHmKgHvkgF4W8C9uZh9yD6wVZUMw","5HTnsJvULhTyyKHtb1ZCHqij6S5S1Va1mVG3JGED8FDRY3HC","5HW5gNSyv2xRXdpsQKXDvM6AJfNYxLi1V3vVacEk3tzFEMHz","5HZ6XfWFX6STZFcaV67kST5GXkywG2k6FV8PfTiqCGEioQ1c","5HZBqryUGJuNJUG7e5oY6M1p4zp9HtEP9cAVMmnynJewUqD7","5HZn9cXLhLJXBGsdZJPt2YT2HbpQ1TFWP3uRYHHjnzWRo1eu","5Hcgj3Qa7LmMpwcGSCGg8N77uvkro7fZvbnj9hqi9poqMCDR","5HjivUtH2soVtHUpeRFaN9YB7cP3iWT2Rr1Nvaaf3j9yET22","5Hm8JHGGSt91tKnkELfGqZpW2guZoWsDnbuG7cDJJ3my8Nu2","5HoLuWtGTmsV1e9EfKEuuf82x4cf7nyYJLBz7fvrxhVh5nqg","5Hp8Ckt5kjxhGkaRJapBXQ7fduR1U4XeJkfB51jezfL5DsnS","5HpasZqGuvQwL1UFLx9YABK8nhwnerkBsQ12p3VBHKVNRNsH"]},"prevotes":{"currentWeight":101,"missing":["5CHDkm33a6wawMagg7M4CGpeYXtYWgbsWRPzrs4iFGTU4S6j","5CKjcnHcCspYD974BDJ8JWXcL3Xt1DxuPbhQkE1RvcnuUTBK","5CLJTem1DvDwmbRiWwX43KXHyYY5SWZ2f2KpJwFiX2zy9u9W","5CMDtbm4XM9W617XnRUC5YvDHTpUYHHqXuSwU6omfGEgfxAY","5CMf5pWBYBnaag7qVHhfXAeJKsx28Dufo6Z1ekMd8fDqCzpY","5CQbFzpuv45gFRE4QKtEmPGskk7FCeU6trdSyTJFukYUZQcA","5CU7UvWgaqbhbH2FxgPh8bn4YXjmkpsiSKLzXh425fKeCeMQ","5CYFfX66GcHfdTRMw1XgS226GJvdvaq8SmsnqFQerRPKJZr5","5CYUkvh2jmQkgm4AT6YvwLDaE7CJK3zmkg7ZtUvavmGsFSQF","5CaBuc5t3hUHWfeR5hzLSn7DKhyZkEDZPZamkTwAyGewkMVp","5CdHYrqsTYmWDoQTE378Y43deqgBccTPRR6Da7tttESSP3GP","5CeCBEcBEVAijVq8UfDwb1pE7ecu5hBZbw2EL6BgGxgco4pb","5D77y3kk2F4WeVGPFGNKHj9KqFDkL3Be78sBN1jLwQ2MNRJm","5DFyPTcYq2UeQyfD7wW1qxWghjDbfkg1jCZDDNXpqz9Dqmdn","5DHG85ALQLBZEv5VcJS4PHf3JuURoVYSZ8Vky43s2ez9kNnc","5DLDwu8BA1nF3243Htp8BprXrbwY47WFBP5uDMWKKjTMdBjb","5DM9HDFujkCJyHCno68C8qeLX43KbafRdLBzyi1hwzrYdfn1","5DU4ykjP5YtuPrCsMmZd7FRkMSVJzv8GoQ6oRsREhUPtf2wx","5DUeSNipPoh4JV7uVpN6AjxYNa8jPyMYA5KutQuPe5F26Bsm","5DcJ48Tw5WsYULGjU6AGFWRq7T7f2ShNPEbp2Snp9VAd3Wj5","5DgwgFj1NXC9dm3HZArna6rW9T3aAKZC5ZfvZM5kwtBirDN9","5DhHepwhWomV6ysktT12KJ818F3X6StwmBNwMYdPZecf2cmx","5DjqAz7EyjHttZDP972zP4RT3Fmn4hsexg5LoD7qhpsdGi65","5DxRcRUuGqrGxG1uMG45FKVSVsc39UWUfSqzWiK79wvF8Sb1","5E9Sru6GEbiDjq4CiZuf2r77JViHEdVbjbdGaBhwGfXfFw9e","5ESnrMXJnp4Hjkv7gmbvUmXYbA1Udfher13fAiNWgaTKwtp9","5Eci1K8B1m6eEWaiqsr4xvb6cg6tajW9GTcnz6GrpYqUYfBK","5EkguJE7pbwi88YHjDh8GkDbgtFJf65qnGyzHJTSFfxT3JPt","5EroE5BJV7n93Z4D9dmpaARa817iHQJ1UyauoYmJFZppKDUB","5EvtGF6W1Xws4ouGdPofgJNFCT6nHR3o3h9oUCkjyUEBsDTk","5F3uDi2ghwFEXEoPMNGiwZmPz6C7DpYdYBejSPjeTwnvrUAK","5F4HbX6C7NRkmuiDZULMoehGTkywNKwMsx9qbCv36QnTEUSb","5F914LRb584dKbz3rakrcB3Uhnk9DyZYfxPL8J8meUX3sLeH","5FBrPeS4tdK4GyaqVXDN2FKMP5KzYPdf9z844gAkDJtPvevH","5FJr162Efkw1VQXZHzKpNptrpCnr4fhAyn724pvpyAmGKXb6","5FcjA9UriUwjKxiNHKN4ksPFqaATRPW9vAUxytfK1V34ektM","5FeaGCh2iwy7pU2nUHFQ8yLGYdujURCU9kyadhW8x95TekA3","5FgCjHUF45dEqw5wAAyuciCUFEs4y53WHQysfSK1Kq2EEFrx","5FiqJD5egss5dKquDJXbGobyzThiQqQcPTSAJwavy1R26c5P","5FoiAwAFd6EybrzRMZffGPqLr1ccWsZA92ZNKvp4q5ZQcCeW","5Fr5PH4198YgsudLPgfGvmGcYVYx6DwPfNXDncPMCWqW4kAi","5FzyvzWqL73NM1QviAyrCAHKx4V8mEzbTSr7CnvyzhUyAy8e","5G4DN9gaKh48LraEQNNhKKGBiWHq3hXr9haPaHpRLEcsQXpk","5GC9BJfGXihQ2nUSarfFZ4zdM6KiTeZZLLScUVHHr4voAPVm","5GGE5mdUM2dncReKfLLbLizqYPSokNz4Tj4Z2n8Kr7DLPrqE","5GGscd7C9EJdb9KJ2Cv9VfwQsERSPiNCdzybWsvJ8WnLB9jW","5GMvuYcVXDZ7s17aCu2eLSc9vS2YaGoLoHB5Di4DTAPYnpx2","5GP7prKCRVuSVkq48VRU98dMP9urPFqF4zq5TAG6rbQUNwv7","5GYAJ8wjQiLsiofoHWdGFjJMnPvuayKLXUfxA745XakPKQNA","5Gk5JCbDs3JJtJEoNPQPj2rXBCE73UaYso2EfHZJ8uZKxcbz","5GkvH2KtWZGmkjzcTyHUr5GQcwhUJBKdXb8CCYV4i6am36xq","5H8wCzaF4zSb2i1yj9Vdsbm4S612JBpq83ZWZXnwUukzxogQ","5HBoJbp4hTrGHhuxxwyYHaYMzeVnocbUcmE9joL2UNb4jLKU","5HGm8NwjzYmnHPSea5duXTzycvhWYwqjANGk4pmNZhv9EQ4h","5HSdfeX1uYLi6NrmTifJwZajS2zE2ZTd7jakHLPgzaqaZF2V","5HW5gNSyv2xRXdpsQKXDvM6AJfNYxLi1V3vVacEk3tzFEMHz","5Hcgj3Qa7LmMpwcGSCGg8N77uvkro7fZvbnj9hqi9poqMCDR","5HjivUtH2soVtHUpeRFaN9YB7cP3iWT2Rr1Nvaaf3j9yET22","5HpasZqGuvQwL1UFLx9YABK8nhwnerkBsQ12p3VBHKVNRNsH"]},"round":1,"thresholdWeight":107,"totalWeight":160},"setId":4821},"id":1}
```

There are indeed many missing prevotes(When we first requested this RPC yesterday, the setId was 4819, currentWeight of prevotes was 100. And now the returned setId is 4821, currentWeight of prevotes is 101. When will it be changed? The currentSetId of Grandpa is 4829 now).

After we tried grandpa.noteStalled function, we found NewAuthorities event in the next session, so the validator set should be re-selected, right? And we also checked validators in Grandpa Authority set, seems that they are all running normally and can produce blocks normally. Don't know why the Grandpa doesn't work.

Comment: For `noteStalled` to work properly you need to remove faulty validators due to which finalization has stopped. You can refer to https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9884/354

Comment: It does make sense. Working on it.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Hi, one more thing, the FINALIZED BLOCK is 16448401 now, so the bestFinalizedBlockNumber should be 16448401 when using noteStalled, right? Actually, we got the finality issue last year because binary_search_by_key problem in pallet-offences. We fixed it and used noteStalled too. But at that time the finalized block was 7958680, and we specified the bestFinalizedBlockNumber as 7958682 and it worked. So a little confused about how to specify bestFinalizedBlockNumber and what does it mean.

Comment: The best finalized block is the last finalized block of your chain, i.e., in your case is `16448401`.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Hi, replaced some faulty validators and tried grandpa.noteStalled function. Then it was fixed. Everything work fine now. We will also continue to monitor the validator status. Thanks for your help!